# Prove that certain family is normal. Is the domain hypothesis not relevant?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{H} = \{ Im(z) > 0 \}$, and $H(\mathbb{H}) = \{ f: \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} : f$ is holmorphic $\}$.

Prove that $\mathbb{F} \subset H(\mathbb{H})$ defined as $\mathbb{F} = \{ f: \mathbb{H} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} : f $ holomrphic and $|f(z)| \neq 3\ \forall z \in \mathbb{H} \}$ is normal in the classic sense (i.e., any $\{f_n\} \subset \mathbb{F}$ has a convergent subsequence in $H(\mathbb{H})$ or a subsquence that converges to $\infty$).

My solution didn't involve $\mathbb{H}$. **Am I missing something?** I did the following:

Let $\{f_n\} \subset \mathbb{F}$. For any $f \in \mathbb{F}$, Image($f$) $\subset A$ or Image($f$) $\subset A^c$, where $A = \{ z: |z| < 3\}$ (because of continuity).

If there are infinite $f_{n_k}$ with image in $A$, they are bounded, so we can use Montel and win.

If there are only finite like that, then after certain $n_0$, $|f_n(z)| > 3\ \forall\ z$. Then $g_n:=\frac{1}{f_n}$ are well defined, don't have any zeroes, and are bounded. By Montel, $\exists\ g_{n_k} \rightarrow g$. By Hurlitz, $g$ doesn't have zeroes or $g$ is zero. Taking $f = \frac{1}{g}$, we get what we want.

Comment: Please fix the notation in the first paragraph. It doesn't make sense. Also, $Im$ seems to have multiple meanings.

Comment: Done! I was using $Im(z)$ for the imaginary part of a point, and $Im(f)$ for the image of a function. I guess it may seem ambiguous, though!

Comment: it is not true that $Image(f) \in A$ or $Image(f) \in A^c$, and the question is about $\mathbb{H}$ an unbounded open, where $Image(f)$ doesn't have to be bounded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks good! Indeed $\mathbb{H}$ is not "special" at least in this regard. Any domain would've sufficed, for the stronger version of Montel's Theorem asserts that if a family of holomorphic functions omits two distinct values, then it is normal. Note that there is no restriction on the domain of the family.